# Convergence and Lebesgue integral of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with values $0$ or $1$. Define

$$
g_n = f_1 + (1-f_1)f_2 + (1-f_1)(1-f_2)f_3 + (1-f_1)(1-f_2)(1-f_3)f_4 + \dots
$$

Prove that the sequence $g_n$ converges a.e.e to a function $g$
Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g_n dm = \int g dm$ Prove or give counterexample.

Clearly $g_n \rightarrow 1$ since as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then for the first time it happens at index $k \in (1,n)$ we have $f_k = 1$ and $f_s = 0$ $\forall s<k$ all the sums inside $g_n$ for all index after $k$ are 0. That's about all I can say about the problem.

Comment: $\{g_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$, assuming $g_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-f_j)\right)f_k\right)$, does not converge to a constant. It converges pointwise to $\sup_k f_k$ (which is also $\max_k f_k$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g_n = f_1 + (1-f_1)f_2 + (1-f_1)(1-f_2)f_3 + (1-f_1)(1-f_2)(1-f_3)f_4 + \dots$

Note that $g_n$ is monotone non-decreasing. I guess you want each $f_n$ measurable. Then so are the $g_n.$

Let $x\in A\subseteq \mathbb R$ for some Lebesgue measurable set $A$.

Suppose $f_j(x)=0$ for all integers $j\le n$. Then, $g_n(x)=0$ and so $g_n(x)\to 0.$

Otherwise, let  $1\le j\le n$ be the first integer such that $f_j(x)=1.$ Then, because each term in $g_n$ after the $j^{th}$ is zero, once $f_j(x)=1,\ g_{k}(x)=1$ for all $k\ge n.$ So, $g_n(x)=f_j(x)=1$ and $g_n(x)=\max\{f_j(x):1\le j\le n\}$. We have then $g_n(x)\to 1.$

In paticular, $g$ is $not$ necessarily constant.

The final claim is true by the montone convergence theorem.